# Facing Hard Time Setting Up Stanford-corenlp in PYTHON

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am not finding a single complete tutorial to use stanford corenlp on my system (windows) using python. After searching a lot I am using StanfordCoreNLP package and using on my system. I dont find any documentation to use it more efficiently. **I want to extract RELATIONS and OPENIE** Since there is no documentation anywhere I just tried putting OpenIE in properties

```
self.props = {
            'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,depparse,dcoref,relation,OpenIE',
            'pipelineLanguage': 'en',
            'outputFormat': 'json'
        }
```

and

```
self.nlp.relations(sentence)
self.nlp.relations(sentence)
```

But it doesnt work! (obviously). I get this error

**AttributeError: 'StanfordCoreNLP' object has no attribute 'relations'**
**AttributeError: 'StanfordCoreNLP' object has no attribute 'openie'**

Can you please guide me to the sources where I can get detailed tutorials for PYTHON?
and I heard that **StanfordCoreNLP** package doesnt have all the features of Stanford-corenlp? Its so confusing! There are so many packages and hard to decide which one to use and which is the right one!
Please help!

````
from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
import logging
import json

class StanfordNLP:
    def __init__(self, host='http://localhost', port=9000):
        self.nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(host, port=port,
                                   timeout=30000)  # , quiet=False, logging_level=logging.DEBUG)
        self.props = {
            'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,depparse,dcoref,relation,OpenIE',
            'pipelineLanguage': 'en',
            'outputFormat': 'json'
        }

    def word_tokenize(self, sentence):
        return self.nlp.word_tokenize(sentence)

    def pos(self, sentence):
        return self.nlp.pos_tag(sentence)

    def ner(self, sentence):
        return self.nlp.ner(sentence)

    def parse(self, sentence):
        return self.nlp.parse(sentence)

    def dependency_parse(self, sentence):
        return self.nlp.dependency_parse(sentence)

    def annotate(self, sentence):
        return json.loads(self.nlp.annotate(sentence, properties=self.props))

    def cor(self, sentence):
        return (self.nlp.coref(sentence))

    # **I tried to get relations and OpenIE**
    def relations(self, sentence):
        return (self.nlp.relations(sentence))

     def openie(self, sentence):
        return (self.nlp.openie(sentence))




    @staticmethod
    def tokens_to_dict(_tokens):
        tokens = defaultdict(dict)
        for token in _tokens:
            tokens[int(token['index'])] = {
                'word': token['word'],
                'lemma': token['lemma'],
                'pos': token['pos'],
                'ner': token['ner']
            }
        return tokens

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sNLP = StanfordNLP()
    text = 'John likes apple. Mary Likes Him'


    s=sNLP.relations(text)
    print(s)
    print("OpenIE:", sNLP.openie(text))
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Stanford CoreNLP (Java code base) provides access to OpenIE and relation extraction.

You can start a server (Java) and access it in Python.  You can get back results in JSON.

There are detailed instructions about using the server here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/corenlp_client.html